# How to avoid using overflow

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am creating a navigation/menu bar and I want it to move horizontally as the cursor moves over it. Currently that is working but I do not want to set the overflow property to hidden because I have drop down tabs that should appear when the cursor is over a menu option. If I were to use overflow then it will cut off at a point but the drop down is also cut off. Inside scroll contains the menu options.

```js
var sum = 0;
$("#scroll li").each(function () {
  sum += $(this).width() + parseInt($(this).css('paddingLeft')) + parseInt($(this).css('paddingRight'))
});
$("#scroll").css('width', sum);

$("#holder").mousemove(function (e) {
  x = -(((e.pageX - $('#scroll').position().left) / $("#holder").width()) * ($("#scroll").width() + parseInt($("#scroll").css('paddingLeft')) + parseInt($("#scroll").css('paddingRight')) - $("#holder").width()));
  $("#scroll").css({
    'marginLeft': x + 'px'
  }); 
});
```

```css
#scroll{
  height: 30px;
  line-height: 30px;
  margin-left: 0;
  padding: 0 10px;
}
#scroll li {
  float: left;
  padding: 0 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="holder" style="width: 800px;line-height: 30px; /* overflow: hidden; */margin-left: 10px;float: left;">
  <div id="scroll" class="nav-collapse"> </div>
</div>
```

Please help provide an alternate solution to using overflow.

Answer (score 0):

Without the entire sample of code or a JSFiddle reference I can't really help you but you can use `overflow-x : hidden` I guess.

Comment: I have tried but using an overflow x or y cuts off the drop down tabs

Comment: Can you make a JSFiddle, it will be easier